# Why there are duplicated review comments?

Tags: bug, review-queues, comments

There is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667279/960757) with two almost identical review comments explaining the same. The first one is missing a dot at the end of the sentence:

[image]

Is it a bug in auto-generated comments or the user just copied the text without the final dot for some reason ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the user copied the text without the dot. The actual message is with a dot, and the message does not get duplicated, I have checked that here [in this review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6589129). There was already a review comment (with a dot), and I selected the same comment -- there is still only one comment.

Comment: I also think it's been just copied (since I've also verified that the comments are not being duplicated - by reviewing just that post I've linked). The author of the first comment [is not between reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6589042) but I'm not sure if that comment could be added automatically by some other tool (e.g. flag).